# No qualifying bean available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have checked all available answers on stackoverflow and still could not find out what is going wrong.
I have the spring boot application class definiton

```
package earnings.evaluatenews;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"earnings.repository", "earnings.evaluatenews"})
public class DuplicateNewsCheckerTestApplication {
}
```

and the below Repository definition

```
package earnings.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TickersAlreadySeenTodayRepository extends JpaRepository<TickersAlreadySeenToday, TickersAlreadySeenToday.TickerToday> {
}
```

I tried writing a @SpringBootTest Test class

```
package earnings.evaluatenews;

import earnings.repository.TickersAlreadySeenTodayRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DuplicateNewsCheckerTestApplication.class,
    properties = {
        "spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/ibkrtest_db"},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class DuplicateNewsCheckerTest {

  @Autowired
  TickersAlreadySeenTodayRepository tickersAlreadySeenTodayRepository;
  . . . 
}
```

But it fails with

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'earnings.repository.TickersAlreadySeenTodayRepository' available:
> expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
> Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have also tried specifying a Test Configuration specifying the same scanned packages as the application being tested, but with the same error.
What am I doing wrong? Please help before I shoot myself.

Comment: Could you share Github repo that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I explicitly pointed to the Repositories by the `EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "...")` Annotation. By default Spring Data looks only in subpackages of the package of the Configuration class, so they say at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-annotations